# How can be three 0-255 integers coded/decoded into/from one number?

Tags: algorithm

With three integers `a,b,c` ranged between 0 and 255, I have to write a function that "stores" the three given numbers into one (d) and another function that is capable to obtain from the fourth number (d), the first three numbers.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried something? What are the conditions for d? How is that question related to C or Java?

Comment: So this is sort of like, if I have the three numbers 12, 34, and 56, I can jam them all together and make the 6-digit number 123456?

Comment: Hopefully your number d will have at least 24 (or more likely 32) bits, to hold all this.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in C, or in Java?

Comment: The question itself is not C or Java  related, but if code snippets are involve, I would prefer C/Java.

The d integer would be another 0-255 number...I think that some (reversible ) bits operations should be applied to the three initial numbers but I don't really have an idea.

Comment: If `d` as well is only 8 bit wide, this is not solvable. `d` needs to be at least 24 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using bitwise shift + masking. Given 4 32bits integers `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, with `a`, `b` and `c` in the range [0..255]:

```
d = (a << 16) | (b << 8) | (c);
```

reverse operation:

```
a = (d >> 16);
b = (d >> 8) & 255;
c = (d) & 255;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
 It looks that for some of us the question was clear enough.

Comment: @Luculus You mean, Keiji was able to just give you the answer, without asking all those questions like I did?  Maybe I was trying to help you work your way through to your own solution. :-)

Comment: @Luculus: Steve is right, I gave you the fish, Steve tried to learn you how to catch it. You should have found the solution yourself.

Comment: This won't work on a 16bit system ... :-P

Comment: @alk: does any 16bits system exist yet? :-D anyway, you're right, you need at least a 24bits system to handle these operations properly. :-P~

Comment: Also I feel this is much to vague, as you give not  a word on which constrains apply to `d` for this to work.

Comment: Just make sure `d` is a long int (or, better yet, an unsigned long int).

Comment: @Steve: specifying "32 bits integer" is not enough ? and why unsigned ?

Comment: @Keiji I think I was replying to alk when I wrote that.  Signed will probably work in this case, but in general code like this can have lots of problems with sign extension, which you either have to fix with lots of extra bitmasks (ugly), or by making the relevant variables unsigned (easy).